# jenkinsfile use traits and other groovy synax

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to use a slightly more complex pipeline build via jenkinsfiles, with some reusable steps as I have a lot or similar projects. I'm using jenkins 2.0 with the pipeline plugins. I know that you can load groovy scripts which contain can contain some generic pieces of code but I was wondering if these scripts can use some of the Object oriented features of groovy like traits. For example say I had a trait called Step:

```
package com.foo.something.ci 
trait Step {                                         
    void execute(){ echo 'Null execution'}                                 
}
```

And a class that then implemented the trait in another file:

```
class Lint implements Step {
    def execute() {
        stage('lint')
        node {
            echo 'Do Stuff'
        }
    }
}
```

And then another class that contained the 'main' function:

```
class foo {
   def f = new Lint()
   f.execute()
}
```

How would I load and use all these classes in a Jenkinsfile, especially since I may have multiple classes each defining a step? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Shared Libaries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). These enable the use of native groovy code in Jenkins.

Your Jenkinsfile would include your shared libary, and the use the classes you defined. Be aware, that you have to pass the steps variable of Jenkins, if you want to use `stage` or the other variables defined in the Jenkins Pipeline plugin.

[Excerpt](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#writing-libraries) from the documentation:
This is the class, which would define your stages

```
package org.foo
class Utilities implements Serializable {
  def steps
  Utilities(steps) {this.steps = steps}
  def mvn(args) {
    steps.sh "${steps.tool 'Maven'}/bin/mvn -o ${args}"
  }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
@Library('utils') import org.foo.Utilities
def utils = new Utilities(steps)
node {
  utils.mvn 'clean package'
}
```